# Como esconder campos do user list sharepoint 2013?

Tags: powershell

Como esconder campos do user list sharepoint 2013? Preciso esconder campos no modo exibição na página userdisp.aspx

Comment: Poderia dar mais detalhes, com print das telas, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado Tiago encontrei a solução usando Power Shell do Sharepoint, veja abaixo o código:

```
$site = SPSite("http://www.seusite")
$web = $site.RootWeb
$spList = $web.SiteUserInfoList
$field = $spList.Fields["DataNascimento"]
$field.ShowInDisplayForm = $true
$field.ShowInEditForm = $true
$field.Update($true)
$spList.Update()
$web.dispose()
$site.dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer ocultar campos de um formulário tanto de Create/Edit/Exib, você pode editar o conteúdo da mesma pelo `SharePoint Designer`.

Ou, via `PowerShell`, como o colega ali disse, você pode usar o comando `.ShowInDisplayForm/.ShowInEditForm` colocando como `'false'` ou `'true'` para cada campo específico.